# How do I make it so only if one key is pressed, other key functions work

Tags: python, pygame

I want it so you can only do the left, right and up moves when the 1 key is pressed first. If I unindent them it works but you can still move without pressing the 1 key so I want to change that.

I tried using a while loop but it would just crash or not work at all
This is the section of code I need to fix.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlI1Q.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code as a code block, not as an image (and definitely not as a photo of a screen...)

Answer (score 1):

Add another state variable to keep track of the general state your game is in, and change it when the user presses `K_1`.

```
run = True
game_state = "menu"
while run:
  if game_state == "menu":
    if keys[pygame.K_1]:
      # clean up sprites or whatnot
      game_state = "playing"
  elif game_state == "playing":
     if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:  # ...
```

There's nothing saying you couldn't separate your game into multiple main loops, though, if that makes things simpler for you, á la

```
def handle_menu():
    while True:
        # draw menu, handle menu input, etc.
        if keys[pygame.K_1]:
             return 1  # assume this means 1 player
        if keys[pygame.K_2]:
             return 2  # assume this means 2 players


def handle_game(player_count):
    while True:
        # draw actual game, etc.

def main():
    player_count = handle_menu()
    handle_game(player_count)
```